# Beautifulsoup - dealing with superscript within span

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, superscript

This is my first web scraper code using BeautifulSoup 4.

This is the HTML segment I am trying to extract information from:

```
    <span class="p24_size" title="Erf Size">
        <img src="/Content/images/Optimized/Icons/icon_erf_new.svg?63fd4a" alt="Erf Size" class="p24_sizeIcon" />
        <span>1 217 m&#178;</span>
    </span>
```

The code had worked previously in the past, but I suspect they subsequently added the superscript.

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
   size = entry.find("span", attrs={"class":"p24_size"}).text
        try:
            size = ''.join(size.split())
            ls_size.append(size[:-2].strip(" m").lstrip())
        except:
            ls_size.append("")
```

This is the error I receive:

```
 File "C:/Users/claus/Desktop/Data/Web scraping/scrape_landvalues_test1.py", line 56, in <module>
    size = entry.find("span", attrs={"class":"p24_size"}).text

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Windows 10 - Spyder (Anaconda)

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with superscript. My bet is that you're not getting the HTML you think you're getting. In other words, `size = entry.find("span", attrs={"class":"p24_size"}).text` this might not be in the source you're requesting.

Comment: Thank you Baduker.

The very first entry was missing the value I was looking for.

By moving entry.find() into the try except solved the problem.

Your advice put me on the right path. Be well.